# Cite a theorem in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to cite a theorem from a reference book. I input the code in the context of  `beamer` as follows:

```
\cite[Theorem 1]{reference book}
```

But it only shows the name of reference book without theorem 1. How to tackle this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If everything works correctly, normally `\cite[Thm.~1]{sigfridsson}` should produce a reference to the work and "Thm. 1". Some citation styles suppress pre- and postnote information, but they should warn you about this. From the description so far it is hard to say what might be going on. Please show us a short example document that shows what you are doing. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. Check the `.log` and `.blg` files for hints.

Comment: I also type the code"usepcakge[citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}. When I cite a theorem, it shows the author and year without the "theorem"

Comment: I'm afraid we need to see more than just that line. At the moment my guess would be that for some reason the citations are not found. Are the citation labels that you see in your document the same as your entry keys in the `.bib` file? Are they shown in bold? Did you run Biber? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: For example. I want to cite theorem 1 in Bob's book. I typed \bibitem{Bob 20} Bob Book's name, 2020 . When I cite the theorem in the text , I input the code \cite[Theorem1]{Bob 20}  , after running pdflatex, it shows as following : [Bob20]       without Theorem 1.

Comment: That means there is an error producing the citations. Note first that entry keys may not contain spaces. So you can't write `\cite{Bob 20}` you can only have `\cite{Bob20}`. Secondly the entry key in your `.bib` file and you `\cite` must match. Thirdly you must run Biber, not BibTeX (see the two links in my last comment).

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I input \cite{Bob20}. When I list the reference books,  I did't use the .bib. I use the following code:   \begin{thebibliography}{10}  \bibitem{Bob20}   \end{thebibliography}

Comment: Oh, you absolutely can not use `thebibliography` with `biblatex`. It would have been much easier to help you if we had known from the start that you used `thebibliography`. That's why we almost always ask for a minimal example document that shows what you are doing.

Comment: Why can not use thebiblioghraphy? It also works when I cite a book , it correctly shows the author and the year.

Comment: The package `biblatex` (`\usepackage{biblatex}`) can not be used together with the bibliography produced by `thebibliography`. The two approaches are completely incompatible. Since you still haven't shown us an example document I have no idea what is happening at your end, so I can not help you until you add the required info to your question.

Comment: If I want to use thebiblioghrpagy,  how to make it show as following "[Bob20, Theorem1]"?

Answer (score 1):

## `Natbib`

Consider using the `citet` and `citep` commands with the `natbib` package.

## Output

[image]

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some references}
Some results from \citet[Theorem 10.22]{kloeden1999numerical}, for more details see \citep[Theorem~10.22]{kloeden1999numerical}.
\vfill
\bibliography{references}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## If using `biblatex`

The same holds here, where we for convenience I use the option `natbib=true`, which gives

[image]

using

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Something}
We see what \citet[Section~1]{einstein} has to say can compare \cite[Section~1]{einstein} with \citep[Section~1]{einstein}.
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It shows that "\newlength{\bibhang}

Comment: The OP is using `biblatex` (according to their comment), so switching to `natbib` might not be the best choice. At the very least it should be motivated.

Comment: Turns out the OP was loading `biblatex` but producing the bibliography with a manual `thebibliography` ...

Comment: I didn't use .bib. I input the code: \begin{thebibliography} \end{thebibliography}

Comment: @mathbeginner in the future use a `.bib` file. Makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: If I used \begin{thebibliography} \end{thebibliography}, how  to make it show as following "[Bob20, Theorem1]"?

Comment: @mathbeginner I'm not sure, but a .bib file is the way to go.